# Using mqtt with pyspark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, mqtt

I'm new to spark and mqtt. I'm trying to with the code using MQTTUtils that I got online named wordcount.py

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.mqtt import MQTTUtils
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Usage: mqtt_wordcount.py <broker url> <topic>"
        exit(-1)

    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingMQTTWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    brokerUrl = sys.argv[1]
    topic = sys.argv[2]

    lines = MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, brokerUrl, topic)
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

and I followed the instruction to installed the mosquitto broker(it's working) ,download the spark-streaming-mqtt-assembly_2.11-1.6.2.jar and run the python script with this command:
~$ spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-mqtt-assembly_*.jar wordcount.py

but the error shown:

from pyspark.streaming.mqtt import MQTTUtils

ImportError: No module named mqtt

Is that I missed out anything from here? 
Thank you

Comment: How to create a [mcve]. Also Spark 2.0+ no longer provides MQTT backend. It has been moved to Spark packages.

Comment: I had the same problema but I was working with the versión 2.0 by now I'm working with the versión 1.6.2 and the script is running.

Answer (score 3):

For spark versions 2.* we can use MQTT in [Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) by including the Bahir Jar.

From pyspark connect to MQTT broker :

```
(spark
    .readStream
    .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
    .option("topic","mytopic")
    .load("tcp://{}".format(broker_uri)))
```

Comment: How to cofigure the format `org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider`